# Simplifying a bruteforce program and adding functionality

Tags: python

I have a password bruteforcer which works with three letters but I have to put in all three letters seperately. Is there a way to make it possible so I can put in all three at once? I convert the word into its ancii code and add 1 to the test variable which is compared to the password.
The code I have:

```
def bruteforce(pw1, pw2, pw3):
    test1 = 64
    pwo1 = ord(pw1)
    test2 = 64
    pwo2 = ord(pw2)
    test3 = 64
    pwo3 = ord(pw3)

    while(test1 != pwo1):
        test1 += 1
    while(test2 != pwo2):
        test2 += 1
    while(test3 != pwo3):
        test3 += 1

    
    print("The password is " + chr(pwo1) + chr(pwo2) + chr(pwo3))
```

What I tried was to convert the string into a list and split the "word" into characters. This didnt work for me, at least I wasnt able to find an explination online how to output the characters from the string into single arguments/variables.

Comment: Just use lists!

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov doesn’t work since I wasn’t able to find a way to implement the list items into the workcycle.

Comment: What do you mean "work cycle"? What did you try using lists? Storing and accessing list indicies is no different than having N individual variables

Comment: @OneCricketeer Tried splitting the string into characters and putting the characters into a list. I can’t find a solution how to convert an entire list of characters into ancii code.

Comment: Unclear what you mean "the string". Can you please show example input and expected output? If you just want a list, you could `l = map(ord, [64, 64, 64])` to get a similar result as the first 6 lines here. Not really clear to me what the while loops are for, but then you can `print(''.join(map(chr, l)))`

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import time
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
#from pyfiglet import Figlet

def time_convert(sec):
  mins = sec // 60
  sec = sec % 60
  hours = mins // 60
  mins = mins % 60
  print("Time Lapsed = {0}:{1}:{2}".format(int(hours),int(mins),sec))

times_to_do = 1

actuall_password = input(Fore.BLUE + 'What password would you like to brute force:   ')
start_time = time.time()

chars = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']
#'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 

while True:
  char_picked1 = (random.choice(chars))
  char_picked2 = (random.choice(chars))
  char_picked3 = (random.choice(chars))
  char_picked4 = (random.choice(chars))
  char_picked5 = (random.choice(chars))
  char_picked6 = (random.choice(chars))
  total_password = (char_picked1 + char_picked2 + char_picked3 + char_picked4 + char_picked5 + char_picked6)
  if total_password == actuall_password:
    print(Fore.GREEN + 'Tried:  ' + total_password)
    print(Fore.GREEN + 'Sucess, your password was:  ', total_password)
    print('This process took', times_to_do, 'attempts!')
    end_time = time.time()
    time_lapsed = end_time - start_time
    print('This process took', time_lapsed, 'seconds to complete this attack')
    break
  else:
    print(Fore.RED + 'Tried: ', total_password)
    times_to_do = (times_to_do + 1)
```

That is a simple version i made with colors!

Comment: Thanks, your solution works great, though it sadly doesn’t integrate my idea of using the ascii code.

Comment: i dont really know what ASCII is, could you explain in further details?

Comment: Also, if my answer  does work enough please mark it as correct!  Thanks!